# create a C# application that demand administrator privileges

Tags: c#, windows, administrator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Run with administrative permission issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130230/run-with-administrative-permission-issue)
>   [How to force a WPF application to run in Administrator mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276674/how-to-force-a-wpf-application-to-run-in-administrator-mode)

I'm stuck with this problem from the morning,I will appreciate it if anybody can help me ,I know that this is my first post,but I may become an active user :p .
anyway my problem is that I want to create a C# application that demand the administrator right from the user in windows 7,so when the user click on it ,the native window of "allowing this application to be executed in administrator rights"(actually I forget what the window says) shows,and a shield icon shows on the icon application indicating to the user that it demands administrator privilege.